# How to get the corresponding data of a max value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query A that results in  :

```
orders    |   date_added 

10        |     2013-01-09        
24        |     2013-01-10          
13        |     2013-01-11
```

I want to get the max number of orders with the **corresponding date** .. 
Here's my query so far

```
 SELECT MAX( orders ) 
 FROM (
         SELECT COUNT( order_id ) AS orders, DATE( date_added ) FROM  `order` 
         WHERE YEAR(date_added) = YEAR( NOW( ) ) 
         GROUP BY DATE( date_added )
        ) AS daily_orders"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will solve this

```
SELECT COUNT( order_id ) AS orders, DATE( date_added ) FROM  `order` 
         WHERE YEAR(date_added) = YEAR( NOW( ) ) 
         GROUP BY DATE( date_added )
ORDER BY orders DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: i LOLed ! I dont know how i missed this